# ghostscript input to read filenames with umlaute from file in CMD

Tags: batch-file, special-characters, ghostscript

I am using Ghostcript 9.20 in Windows command prompt. Ghostscript shall read filenames from a file, though some of the files have "Umlaute" for e.g. üäö such in a filename "Jürgen1.pdf" 
"Jürgen2.pdf". But Ghostscript 9.20 swallows the umlaut ü and can't read the filenames with Umlaute at all. What am I doing wrong?

```
chcp 1252
set file_output=Jürgen_merged
dir "Jürgen*.pdf" /b /o:n > files.txt
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Gawk\gawk4.1\gawk" "{ print \"\042\" $0 \"\042\" }" files.txt > files.lst
"C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.20\bin\gswin64c" -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o "%file_output%.pdf" @files.lst
del files.lst
```

Comment: It should work, I suggest you open a bug report with a file which exhibits the problem. Just the one file and a simple command line, no scripts, please.

Comment: [The Windows command prompt is *NOT* a DOS prompt!](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/the-windows-command-prompt-is-not-a-dos-prompt/)

Comment: I tried to convert the @files.lst into UTF8 with this iconv -f WINDOWS-1252 -t UTF-8 files.txt > files.lst and it still does not work or swallows the Umlaut.

Answer (score 1):

Now with the update to [Ghostscript 9.21](https://ghostscript.com/Ghostscript_9.21.html) die @file function and "Umlaute" in this file works. The bug is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* the problem is that the @file.list syntax doesn't support the conversion from the Windows codepage to the UTF-8 which we have to use internally. This is because the contents of @file.list options are actually handled in Postscript (which doesn't know about codepages and the like). So I *think* if you convert your file.lst file to UTF-8 encoding, it might work.

Comment: No it does not work see my post about converting from iconv -f WINDOWS-1252 -t UTF-8 txt. I checked the file with Notepad++ and the file was indeed converted to UTF-8 without BOM. Ghostscript still omits the Umlaute und subsequently can't read the files from the file list.

Comment: Well, as my colleague said above, open a bug at https://bugs.ghostscript.com/ attach what we need to reproduce the problem, and we'll look into it.

Comment: I am not familiar with these kind of bug reporting, since I am not a professional user. Jut use Ghostscript as a private user. I will try my best. In the meantime i did a work around with passing it to a script through gawk and then again to a variable like this

Comment: Here the code: gawk" "BEGIN{ORS=\"\n\";RS=\"\"}{gsub(\"\n\",\"\042 \042\")}1" files.lst > files.txt

set /P files=<files.txt